# Excel Split and Insert Cells Intelligently

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm working a personal project, a pretty simple web scraper. I've got my results stored as a CSV with Title, URL, and ID. ID contains strings of results found through regex matching (ex: An ID cell could be "1234567", "1111111 2222222", etc.) Splitting cells into columns is trivial, but how can I easily split these IDs while maintaining links to the relevant Title and URL? I'm working with a couple thousand pages, so going by hand isn't much of an option.

**Example:**

Initial:
"Homepage", foo.bar/home, 1111111 2222222

After:
"Homepage", foo.bar/home, 1111111 
"Homepage", foo.bar/home, 2222222

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in vba should do the trick.  This has no error checking and isn't optimized for speed but should be alright for this.  It will create a new sheet and split the data the way it looks like you want.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim lRow As Long, curRow As Long, pasteRow As Long
Dim dataWS As Worksheet, pasteWS As Worksheet
Dim ArrID() As String
Dim i As Long

'Since csv will only have one sheet
Set dataWS = Sheets(1)
Set pasteWS = Worksheets.Add
pasteRow = 1

lRow = dataWS.Range("A" & dataWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For curRow = 1 To lRow
    ArrID() = Split(dataWS.Range("C" & curRow).Value, " ")
    For i = 0 To UBound(ArrID)
        If Len(ArrID(i)) > 0 Then
            pasteWS.Range("A" & pasteRow & ":B" & pasteRow).Value = dataWS.Range("A" & curRow & ":B" & curRow).Value
            pasteWS.Range("C" & pasteRow).Value = ArrID(i)
            pasteRow = pasteRow + 1
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant:

1. split into columns.  I used text to column, space and comma delimiters, treat consecutive delimiters as one.
2. Throw into pivot table
3. Add title, url and ID1 into rows.
4. Go to field settings for each field, turn off subtotals.  On the "Layout and Print" tab, Show items in Tabular Form and Repeat Item Labels.
5. Copy the data into a new sheet.
6. Swap out ID1 with ID2 in pivot table rows.  Copy into the new sheet.

[image: linked image - helps show method]